# Windows 10 Python 2.7 installing TensorFlow 1.4 using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I need to run an application that was written in Python 2.7 with Tensorflow 1.4.0. I have installed Python 2.7.18 on x64 Windows 10 and I am running into a couple of issues:

1. `pip2` is not recognised. To run pip I have to use `py -2 -m pip`.
2. `py -2 -m pip install tensorflow` throws an `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`. If I change it to `py -2 -m pip install tf` I can only retrieve version 1.0.0. `py -2 -m pip install tf==1.4.0` also fails to find the version.

Installing other packages this way (e.g. numpy) works fine. How can I install the required version of tensorflow?

Comment: did you try `pip install tensorflow==1.4.0`

Comment: This uses pip3 with my default Python 3.12.

Comment: Change the pip call to the one you need: `py -2 -m pip install tensorflow==1.4.0`, but not sure if it works since I cannot see Windows files on https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.4.0/#files

Comment: As mentioned above `py -2 -m pip install tensorflow` installs 1.0.0 and trying newer versions like 1.4.0 throws `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.4.0`.

Since it doesn't show up on the pypi page, is it possible that it's not supported at all?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a python2 docker container :-)

Answer (score 0):

Old TF versions with Python 2 are no longer supported on Windows via pip. What worked for me was to make the minimal changes to the code needed to run Python 3.6, which supports TF 1.4. A more complicated option that works with Python 2 would be to build TensorFlow from source.

Comment: Be great if you could provide before and after examples so that others can see how to update their code. It will make your answer more useful to future users. Thanks

Comment: This did not require tensorflow-specific code changes. For my use case, it was mostly converting `print x` to `print(x)` and `xrange` to `range`.